Getting "Error 401: disabled_client" in Google OAuth API Before Using the API
I recently set up a new Gmail API project in the Google Cloud Console, but I’m facing an issue before even getting the chance to use it. Whenever I try to authorize the API, I receive this error:
Error 401: disabled_client
Request details: flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Ensured the response_type=code parameter is included in the authorization URL.
Verified that my OAuth credentials (client ID and secret) are configured correctly in my application.
Tried logging into the Google Cloud Console to check the status of my OAuth client, but I can’t access the console, as my client appears to have been disabled before I could use the API.
I’ve encountered this issue across multiple accounts, and each time, I receive the same error. I’ve also selected the following scopes:
.../auth/gmail.readonly
.../auth/gmail.modify
https://mail.google.com/

Has anyone experienced this issue or can provide guidance on resolving it? I’m unsure if I missed a configuration step or if this is related to a Google policy. Any advice on how to re-enable my API or gain Console access to address this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Please edit your question and include [example] as well as what type of client you created in google cloud console.
